# In Village (2011) are the winning strategies really balanced?

Tags: village

I've been playing Village often with my girl (2 player game only) - it is more a matter of making more points than actually competing (as in blocking the other player). I have not, so far, played the game with more than 2 players.

However, what I noticed is that the "easy" way to get points is selling on the market. Can it actually be beaten? I've tried, at the beginning of several games to do something different, like "in this game, I will settle for politics" - or religion, or whatever. At mid-game, no matter what, I have to resort to create and sell some goods to keep up with the points.

Comment: It turned out we had misinterpreted the rules and were playing with more cards available on the market - as if it was a 4 player game, but in a 2 player game.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I would say that you can block the other players, particularly with the single cube on the market.

Is the other player building up a stock of things to sell on the market? Trigger the market day early. They will, at the very least, have to spend green cubes and time to sell their goods (and won't have stocked up on so much to sell); if they don't have green cubes (or can't afford the time) then all the better.

Secondly, I would suggest that a winning strategy does not necessarily need to be monomaniacally focused on a single area; politics can be used to grease the wheels of travel by providing you with the cubes etc.

Comment: :-) Having to resort to pick the Market action in order to stop anyone from winning through the market sort of makes my point: one has to pick the market action, or perish.

Comment: I disagree. Your point was that you had to _sell_ things on the market (and therefore spend actions building up the necessaries to sell on the market). The counter only involves a single action; you trigger the market day.